# How to remove old spark streaming data?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs

How to remove old spark streaming data?

We have spark streaming process which reads data from kafka, converts data and writes to hdfs.

And we have another spark process which creates spark sql query to spark streaming results created by first process.

The first process writes checkpoints to hdfs, their directories:

```
/commits
/metadata
/offsets
/sources
```

and also this process creates directory /_spark_metadata in directory which setup for streaming result.

We did not find a way to remove the streaming data that is no longer needed.
If we just delete the files that made the streaming, the first process produces an error, the second one, too. If you delete the directory
/_spark_metadata, the search process starts to search, but it looks slowly, and the first process produces an error until you delete the directory with its metadata

How remove old spark streaming data correctly?